# Gridview not aligning properly on ipad bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

As i am new to bootstrap i started making a website: [Website](http://oostenrijk-vakantiehuizen.com).

Now when you view this website on ipad the alignment of the houses are wrong. As you can see here:

[image: Example]

The code containing the gridview:

```
<div class="house-grid">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Huizen</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/BHM-02-12579_10A_516x258_jpg_472.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Huis 1</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
                <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/fotos-oude-computer-4021-600x300.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Huis 2</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
                <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/HFN-02-13024_516x258_jpg_1910.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Huis 3</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
                <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
                 <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/BHM-02-12579_10A_516x258_jpg_472.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Huis 1</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
                <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/fotos-oude-computer-4021-600x300.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Huis 2</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
                <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/HFN-02-13024_516x258_jpg_1910.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Huis 3</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
                <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how do i make it so it aligns next to eachother and not in groups of 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you layout you have used multiple `.row` with 3 elements inside it.

But in responsive view `.row` can be split thats why after 3 elements there is a break you should use one row with all elements bootstrap will handle it in all the screens

```
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/BHM-02-12579_10A_516x258_jpg_472.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Huis 1</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
                <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/fotos-oude-computer-4021-600x300.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Huis 2</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
                <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/HFN-02-13024_516x258_jpg_1910.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Huis 3</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
                <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/BHM-02-12579_10A_516x258_jpg_472.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Huis 1</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
                <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/fotos-oude-computer-4021-600x300.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Huis 2</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
                <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/HFN-02-13024_516x258_jpg_1910.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Huis 3</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
                <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

> Above is the example in which i have used only one row and all the elements are inside that row

Answer (score 0):

You could put all your columns in one row, rather than two:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/BHM-02-12579_10A_516x258_jpg_472.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Huis 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
        <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/fotos-oude-computer-4021-600x300.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Huis 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
        <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/HFN-02-13024_516x258_jpg_1910.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Huis 3</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
        <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="images/BHM-02-12579_10A_516x258_jpg_472.jpg">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Huis 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
      <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="images/fotos-oude-computer-4021-600x300.jpg">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Huis 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
      <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="images/HFN-02-13024_516x258_jpg_1910.jpg">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Huis 3</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.</p>
      <p><a href="huis-pagina.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer informatie</a></p><p><a style="background-color: #088A08;" href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Neem contact op</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```